# clic button to launch r script

Tags: r

I would like to create a run button for my Rstudio script on my desktop so that when I double click on the button my script launches, but I'm struggling a bit. Do you have any ideas please?

Comment: Hello Arnaud! On stackoverflow the only language that is permitted is English. This is so a broarder amount of people can find questions and use the answers when they have coding problems. Also your question is not package or code specific.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because posts need to be in English on this Stack.

Comment: it's rectified yet

Comment: When you say "script launches", you're talking about having a R process running something, not having the RStudio IDE open and run it, is that correct? Which OS are you using?

Comment: @SolarMike, it seems your original reason for closing is remedied, please consider changing your close-vote.

Comment: @r2evans, exactly, that's it
i use windows 10

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your R script. Mine is `~/StackOverflow/19091739/73472411.R`, and it contains these contents:

   ```r
   message("hello world")
   Sys.sleep(10)
   ```
2. Right-click on the Windows desktop, and select *New >> Shortcut*.
3. Type in the path to your `R` executable, but use `Rscript.exe` instead. Add to that your filename. Mine looks like this:

   ```
   C:\R\R-4.1.2\bin\Rscript.exe c:\Users\r2\StackOverflow\19091739\73472411.R
   ```

   Note that if there are spaces anywhere, you'll need to quote the path(s) appropriately.

This creates a shortcut icon on the desktop that, when pressed, opens a non-interactive R session, displays "hello world", waits 10 seconds, then exits/disappears.